# IIF Function (Access)

Tags: ms-access, iif

Any Access guru's out there that can help me out? Trying to figure out how to achieve the following: I want a query to go through each individual in the table of individuals and return those who have a true value in Christmas List field. This database is old and was created with the CompanyName as the primary key for table of companies (I know - bad design). To get around having a company with multiple locations they created an addressline field. That way if "Company y" opens a new location in San Diego, they add an entry of "Company Y - San Diego" and enter "Company Y" in the addressline. Then for individuals who don't have a company, they are entered in a dummy company entry of "Home". So ideally, what I want this query to do is to loop through, grab all the individuals who are supposed to be on the Christmas List, If the addressline field ISN'T NULL I want CompanyName to equal the AddressLine, but If CompanyName = "Home" I want CompanyName to equal "" (emptry string). Also some people have a overnight address, since their normal address is a P.O Box. The below query I have working for me mostly, however I am not clear on how to make the companyname blank in the returned results if CompanyName="Home".

```
SELECT tblIndividuals.FirstName, tblIndividuals.LastName, IIf([tblcompanies].[addressline] Is Not Null,[tblcompanies].[addressline],[tblcompanies].[companyname]) AS CompanyName, IIf([tblIndividuals].[MailingAddress1] Is Null,[tblCompanies].[MailingAddress1],[tblIndividuals].[MailingAddress1]) AS MailingAddress1, IIf([tblIndividuals].[MailingAddress1] Is Null,[tblCompanies].[MailingAddress2],[tblIndividuals].[MailingAddress2]) AS MailingAddress2, IIf([tblIndividuals].[MailingAddress1] Is Null,[tblCompanies].[MailingAddress3],[tblIndividuals].[MailingAddress3]) AS MailingAddress3, IIf([tblIndividuals].[MailingAddress1] Is Null,[tblCompanies].[MailingAddress4],[tblIndividuals].[MailingAddress4]) AS MailingAddress4, IIf([tblIndividuals].[MailingAddress1] Is Null,[tblCompanies].[City],[tblIndividuals].[City]) AS City, IIf([tblIndividuals].[MailingAddress1] Is Null,[tblCompanies].[State],[tblIndividuals].[State]) AS State, IIf([tblIndividuals].[MailingAddress1] Is Null,[tblCompanies].[Zip],[tblIndividuals].[Zip]) AS Zip
FROM tblIndividuals INNER JOIN tblCompanies ON tblIndividuals.CompanyName = tblCompanies.CompanyName
WHERE (((tblIndividuals.ChristmasList)=True))
Order by [tblIndividuals].[companyname];
```

I would love to have it sort by CompanyName Values (A-Z), THEN by Individual's last names (A-Z) if at all possible. I will not pretend to be great at SQL, so any help you could give me would be hugely appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a UNION query, for example:

```
SELECT i.FirstName, i.LastName, 
       IIf(c.[addressline] Is Not Null,
           c.[addressline],c.[companyname]) AS CompanyName, 
       c.[MailingAddress1] AS MailingAddress1, 
       c.[MailingAddress2] AS MailingAddress2, 
       c.[MailingAddress3] AS MailingAddress3, 
       c.[MailingAddress4] AS MailingAddress4, 
       c.[City] AS City, 
       c.[State] AS State,
       c.[Zip] AS Zip
FROM tblIndividuals i
INNER JOIN tblCompanies c ON i.CompanyName = c.CompanyName
WHERE i.ChristmasList=True
AND i.[MailingAddress1] Is Null
UNION
SELECT i.FirstName, i.LastName, 
       IIf(c.[addressline] Is Not Null,c.[addressline],
           c.[companyname]) AS CompanyName, 
       i.[MailingAddress1] AS MailingAddress1, 
       i.[MailingAddress2] AS MailingAddress2, 
       i.[MailingAddress3] AS MailingAddress3, 
       i.[MailingAddress4] AS MailingAddress4, 
       i.[City] AS City, 
       i.[State] AS State,
       i.[Zip] AS Zip
FROM tblIndividuals i
INNER JOIN tblCompanies c ON i.CompanyName = c.CompanyName
WHERE i.ChristmasList=True
AND i.[MailingAddress1] Is Not Null
```

You can wrap the query in brackets to create a derived table that you can sort using the query design window.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, etc 
FROM ( <union query> ) As q
Order by q.[companyname]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and time. Access just gives me the following "helpful" error of "Syntax error in union query." As I am unfamiliar with unions in general, I am not sure where to even begin. Any help you think you could give me?

Comment: I had missed two aliases and an extra bracket. Try it now.

Comment: It runs now, but CompanyName is still pulling in the word "Home" instead of leaving that one blank. Is there a way to leave that CompanyName empty if CompanyName equals "Home"?

Comment: Yes, but I have no idea which half of the union Home belongs to.

Comment: Do you want c.[addressline] if company name is null, or what?

Comment: Is there a way you can break down what you posted in human readable speech, so I can help identify where in the union it should be? As I said in my opening post, I am an SQL noob, just able to do simple select statements, etc. The union you posted I am not even able to follow very well. Alternatively, can you show what it would look like on either side of the Union, and I can run both and see which works :-p. Sorry about this, but I am very greatful for your help.

Comment: No one in "Home" would have anything in the AddressLine field. I want c.[addressline] if c.[addressline] isn't null

Comment: I should clarify that I want c.[companyname] to equal c.[addressline] if c.[addressline] isn't null.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12809/discussion-between-remou-and-user1389971)